# How do I make my turtle happy?

Tags: psychology, turtles, toys

My turtle, Tyler, has recently been getting really sad. He is perfectly healthy. But he is eating slower, and sleeping more - thus he seems sad, which makes me sad!

Are there toys that I could buy, or different foods that I can give him? It might be his food. Thank you!

Comment: What kind of turtle is he, and what kind of enclosure do you have him in?  What does he eat?

"Sad" turtle behavior is often because of a lack of UV light, being too cold, or other problems with the turtle's environment.

Comment: It is a bog turtle, and I am looking at the light right now. It seems like one of the  bulbs have broken. My UV light has three small bulbs. His environment is a good size. He has space to stay on and, and plenty of toys and places to swim. I am kind of a minimalist, so there's some empty space, a little bit, for the turtle to just sit and feel spacious. @Meg

Comment: That sounds good, it doesn't need to be elaborate.

Comment: @Meg That sounds pretty good! Do you happen to know where I could find a new bulb?

Comment: If you have a local aquarium store they often carry them, or there are online pet stores like chewy.com and event amazon.com carries some reptile supplies.  Depending on what type and style of light fixture you use, you may even need to contact the manufacturer for help in finding the right replacement bulbs.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is that you could create a basking tank with an UVB lightbulb. Also, you could add a few feeding guppies in the water you could add a few feeding guppies to keep him active and happily chasing guppies.

You could also get another turtle to keep company.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can I find any of these items at the local perstore? (Petco) And do you think I might be able to buy a boy? (I have a girl)

Comment: of course, you will get it at petco.com but I kinda don't trust Petco personally so you could try http://www.theturtlesource.com.I don't live in the US even then they helped me with a tortoise diet I could prepare at home via email specific to my tortoise breed. They have everything your turtle could ever need and you could ask questions via email and they reply.

Answer (score 2):

Sad turtle behavior is usually a result of a turtle being too cold, lacking UV light, or going into a semi-dormant state (brumation), which can naturally happen when the days are shorter and nighttime temps are lower in fall and winter.

Replacing your heat and UV bulbs can help perk him back up, and if you don't have a thermometer already, you may want to check that the tank temperature is proper.

If you think he's bored and needs enrichment, live food is a good way to go, or you can hide treats for him to forage for (make sure you take out anything he doesn't find promptly, this can get messy).  Anecdotally, some turtles seem to enjoy a natural looking background image taped on the outside back of the tank to look at.  I can't vouch for that making a difference to my turtle, but it can't hurt!